# How is the asset URL generated for the Shopify CDN?

Tags: api, cdn, shopify

Assume I have an image uploaded to a store on Shopify called 'logo.png'.

In a liquid template I can generate a URL for it like this:

```
{{ 'logo.png' | asset_url }}
```

This generates a URL such as:

> http://static.shopify.com/s/files/1/0072/7952/t/2/assets/logo.png?100239

I want to generate this URL outside of Shopify for use in a third party app.

From the Shopify code at https://github.com/Shopify/pixelprinter/blob/master/app/liquid/filters/shop_filter.rb#L84

I can see how to use the shop id to generate everything except the `'/t/2'` segment.

What determines this final segment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not depend on the url being generated in a specific way.  As you have pointed out, you can use the asset_url filter in liquid and you can use the [Asset API](http://api.shopify.com/asset.html) to get the url for an asset from an app.

If you are just curious, then I believe the final segment in your case specifies that it is a theme with id 2.

Comment: OK, thanks I'll use the Asset API. Is the PixelPrinter source now out of date? I've used it as a reference in the past.

Comment: I am not very familiar with it, but it doesn't look like it will use the CDN if the shop is using a plan that supports it.  It also looks like it suffers from a shop 100,000,000 bug in resources_dir which I preemptively fixed in Shopify.  But overall it looks like it is a good reference.