# Shopify: Using an Assets directory string with a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, shopify

I'm using a fancyzoom jQuery plugin on a Shopify site, and I need to specify a directory path for the shadows, closebox, etc images.

Here is the jQuery plugin language:

```
var zoomImagesURI   = 'DirectoryStringGoesHere/'; // Location of the zoom and shadow images


inImage2.setAttribute('src',zoomImagesURI+'closebox.png');
```

A similar question to mine was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953950/how-is-is-the-asset-url-generated-for-the-shopify-cdn), and the answer is bascially to use the Shopify API. The useful bits of the API that I found are these:

> **key**
>
> { "key" : "assets/bg-body-green.gif"}
>
> The path to the asset within a shop. For example, the asset
>   bg-body-green.gif is located in the assets folder.
>
> **public_url**
>
> { "public_url" : "http://static.shopify.com/assets/bg.gif?1"}
>
> The public facing URL of the asset.

This seems like it should be simple, yet I could not get this to work for me. Any suggestions?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use Liquid and use the asset_url filter. That's one way to do it with no chance of failure.

eg:

```
var fizzbuzz = "{{ 'some_asset.png' | asset_url }}";
```